# Glob behavior differences between script and command line

Tags: bash

Note the distinct behavior of the following between the shell and a function defined in the shell:

First: try directly on the shell:

```
0:23:34/shared $ls -dlrta ?pectral*
-rw-r-----@  1 steve  staff  4430060 Oct 27 10:38 SpectralClustering.pdf
-rw-r-----@  1 steve  staff   840539 Oct 27 14:54 spectralEigenValues.pdf
-rw-r-----@  1 steve  staff   839485 Oct 27 14:56 Spectral EigenMatrices.pdf
-rw-r-----@  1 steve  staff  1928395 Oct 29 23:10 spectralClusteringlecture.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  45 steve  staff     1530 Nov  6 10:37 spectral.new
-rw-r--r--   1 steve  staff     5452 Nov 13 01:26 SpectralClusteringSuite.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steve  staff     7935 Nov 13 01:26 SpectralClustering.scala
drwxr-xr-x  40 steve  staff     1360 Dec 21 08:32 spectral.old
drwxr-xr-x  45 steve  staff     1530 Dec 23 09:06 spectral
```

Now let's define a function containing that command:

```
$type ldr
ldr is a function
ldr ()
{
    ls -dlrta $1
}
```

Let's try that function:

```
0:23:06/shared $ldr ?pectral*
ls: EigenMatrices.pdf: No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x  45 steve  staff  1530 Dec 23 09:06 Spectral
```

Any hints on how to reconcile / force identical behavior in the function as to the (desired) beahvior of directly on the command line?

Comment: The shell in which you invoke the function is expanding the glob itself, so what gets passed to the function is a list of matching filenames in the current directory - some of them containing spaces. Then the unquoted parameter `$1` in your function is breaking due to word-splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs to be

```
ldr () { ls -dlrta "$@"; }
```

use the quoted form `"$@"` to use *all* the arguments, with whitespace protected.

Comment: I suppose you could do `alias ldr='ls -dlrta'` to get the same effect